# Demonstrate that this system is an ICS

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

**Question:** Given the set of vectors $(1,1), (-1,1), (2,2) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ demonstrate that this system of vectors forms an Indeterminate Compatible System (Rouché-Fröbenius theorem).

I have tried to demostrate it by using matrices:

$
M^+=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 &  0\\
2 & 2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$

$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1\\
2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$

$
X=\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
$

So, $MX=0$ is:

$
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
-x & y\\
2x & 2y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
$

But $rank(M^+)=rank(M)=$ number of variables $=2$ which would mean it's a Determinate Compatible System by the R-F theorem.

Comment: I am not familiar with the vocabulary, do you have to show that $\ker M = \{0\}$? So that there may not be any solution to $AX = B?$

Comment: @JulesBesson I have to show that one of the vectors is a linear combination of the other two, in this case we can observe that $v_3$=2$v_1$, meaning that if you had a system with $v_1$ and $v_2$, for example, you would form a base in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Ah ok so a related family, so you clearly have $(v_1,v_2)$ that forms a free family of $\mathbb{R}^2$, but its dimension is $2$ so it is a basis.

Comment: @JulesBesson Yes, precisely, the only problem is I don't know why my calculations don't add up to the demonstration that the system formed is an ICS.

Comment: I'm writing the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of  Rouché-Fontené theorem is wrong, (and it is not a very efficient way to do it, cardinal of the family is the best answer, or $v_3 = 2 v_1$). If you wish to use your theorem no matter what, here is how you should do it:
Always use column vectors to avoid confusion
$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
Thus
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$M_+ = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 1 & 1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$$

and $\text{rk} (M_+) = 2 = \text{rk} (M)$ which means your family is related.

Comment: Understood! So, MX would look like: 

$
\begin{pmatrix}
x & -x & 2x \\
y & y & 2y \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: No, for $X = (x_1,x_2,x_3)^T$, $$MX = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 \\ x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 \end{pmatrix} .$$ What you wrote is $DM$ with $$ D = \begin{pmatrix} x & 0 \\ 0 & y  \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: To conclude, I realized that MX would be a system of 3 variables but 2 equations and DM would be a system of 2 variables but 3 equations, or am i wrong? Moreover, $MX = (DM)^{-1}$.

Comment: If you really want to understand the concept of vectors, matrices etc, you should instead read a book about linear algebras, it explains how linear morphisms, vectors, matrices and linear systems are linked (and the same) But $MX$ is a vector, however $MX = B$ is a system of linear equations. Plus you can't invert a vector, it makes no sense.